# Import text file to code in D

Tags: compilation, d

I'm doing some shader programming in D, and what I want to do is write my shaders in text files, but during compilation have the text files be put into the executable / library, just like a normal string would.

Is there a way to do this in D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Import Expressions](http://dlang.org/expression#ImportExpression).

```
string shaderText = import("shader.txt");
```

Make sure you use the `-J` compiler switch to supply the directory of the shader.